# Copying files with name containing just numbers using a batchfile

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-management

I have a Directory with a deep Directory->Sub-directory tree structure. I need to write a batch file to copy all the numbered files (files with names as digits and no alphabetic characters) from all the sub-directories.

For example, a sub-directory might contain the following files:

- WR10091.txt
- AX10091.htm
- 10091.txt
- AX10091.xml
- 10091.xml

I need to copy 10091.txt and 10091.xml to another location. I can copy files like AX10091.xml and AX10091.htm by specifying AX*.*. But I cannot figure out how to copy just numbered files with no alphabetic characters. There are thousands of directories and the directory structure does not have any pattern (the depth of a tree branch can vary considerably).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "source=%cd%"
    set "target=x:\target\folder"

    for /r "%source%" %%a in (*) do (
        (for /f "delims=0123456789" %%b in ("%%~na") do (
            break
        )) || echo copy "%%~fa" "%target%"
    )
```

In this code the `for %%a` will iterate over all the files under the indicated folder. For each of them, the `for /f %%b` will try to tokenize the file name (`%%~na`) using numbers as delimiters. If the file name only contains numbers, there will be nothing to process (only delimiters) and the inner `for` raises errorlevel. This is checked with conditional execution (the code after the `||` is executed if the previous command fails) and if errorlevel was raised the `copy` operation is echoed to console.

If the output is correct, remove the `echo` to perform the copy.

*note*: the `break` in the inner `for` loop is included just to have a command that does nothing when files with non numeric names are found.

Comment: Oooh - very efficient, clever, and elegant. Use of DELIMS to remove digits is interesting reverse thinking, and BREAK and the FOR loop return code are both rarely seen constructs.

Comment: This can be simplified into a one line command to be executed from the command line (no batch). I'm assuming the current directory is the source root: `for /r %a in (*) do (for /f "delims=0123456789" %%b in ("%%~na") do break)||copy "%a" "targetPath"`

Comment: @dbenham, nice. Just some corrections (copy/paste `%%` problems) and "improvements" (less verbose) if someone wants to use it from command line:  `for /r %a in (*) do @(for /f "delims=0123456789" %b in ("%~na") do @break)||echo copy "%a" "targetPath"`

Comment: I've never seen the `for loop return code` before. Very, very nice! `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims="  %%a in ('dir /b /s /a:-d "*"') do (
    echo %%~na|findstr /e /b /r "[1-9]*" >nul 2>nul && (
        copy %%~fa c:\somewhere\
    )

)
```

should be executed in the same directory as the files.

Comment: See there the problem. I cannot manually go the same directory each time as the number of sub-directories are in thousands.

Comment: @DippedBits - now it is recursive

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/s/a-d ^| findstr /reic:"\\[0-9][0-9]*\..*" /c:"\\[0-9][0-9]*"') do copy "%%~a" "targetDir"
```

This might not work with XP and/or Vista, but this can be fixed if needed (see [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman)).